In the long term, are there plans to convert the Meta Stack Exchange network into a decentralized solution?
It's my first time on Meta Stack Exchange, but when I read the topics on what is going on in development of the platform, my first thoughts were, why are most of the Topics voted down so much?
For example, the topic User activation: Learnings and opportunities is downvoted 45 times, and the comments are about getting the popcorn out.
Other, similar questions I could have asked:

Why is the META-network a centralized solution?
Does anybody think about a decentralized solution for the sharing of knowlegde?
Why does Meta Stack Exchange does not think of the internet as a cloud?

So when something grew up and everything was fine during the first years of pioneering, but then the service gets bigger and bigger and the problem of how to attract more new participants arises to keep everything going from a commercial point of view, someone should ask if it is with a centralized solution the right way to make use of the internet as the largest cloud on this earth.
The internet IS the cloud. There is no need to put big, huge centralized structures in it to pervert the initial, decentralized layout of the world wide web.
The internet IS a huge, decentralized structure, and we should make use of it in the way it IS layed out. We should NOT try to convert it into a centralized structure based thing - that is NOT the nature, the intial spirit of the whole internet thing.
So when you try to put in a screw with a hammer, it does not work well. Everything on this earth should be used as it IS layed out for. Lay out a decentralized network, use it in a decentralized manner.
So what are the plans to convert the Meta Stack Exchange network into a decentralized solution, if there are any?

What do you even mean with a decentralized solution? Blockchain? Cloud? What would be the benefit? What does this have to do with downvotes on certain questions?

Removed a few unnecessary things. We know that people are thankful, they don't need to explicitly mention it every time. Anyway, is your question directed towards the company or the user community? Answers may differ. The company is primarily profit-oriented (it used to be a bit different like 10 years ago) and if your idea is not increasing the profit margin for them, they'll not plan for it. The community constantly thinks different and is at odds with the company for years now. Also, your question could be a bit more focused. We rather prefer more questions but each on one topic only.

"why are most of the Topics voted down so much" Again not very precise. On meta or on the main (real content) question sites? This is an additional question and it's likely answered already. You can search on meta. One famous discussion from 10 years ago (closed now) is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

@JeanotZubler "What would be the benefit?" One could probably lookup general advantages of decentralized solutions and see if they could apply here. Typically empowerment of single actors, anonymity or resilience are mentioned. I guess the connection to downvotes may be that in a decentralized knowledge network subgroups may be able to maybe better organize themselves and therefore may be able to maybe avoid the friction that obviously exists here with all the downvoted questions. Maybe that's the idea here. I didn't understand the "that's the spirit of the internet" thing.

We are also decentralized, right? Each site in the network has their own meta as well. This very site tries to govern overarching principles. It just happens to be that in recent years the resistance to change has grown as the plans presented by the company appear to be mis-aligned with the expectations of the community at large. Efforts are made to close that gap but we have a long way to go, specially when we keep circling the gap. That explains the discourse you notice. I personally don't think changing the structure will help getting a better reception of new proposals.

Your question also makes the gross assumption that 'decentralized is better than centralized' - both concepts have merit and are contextual and relative.

I don't understand what you mean by decentralized. For me, SE sites are decentralized at the atomic level, where each user is able to conduct the site curation and community moderation autonomously. How can you be more decentralized than that?

@AugustoVasques Decentralized basically means that the content is stored in many independent objects and the only fixed thing is something like a protocol that everything one has to observe. Here the content is all stored on a few centralized servers. That's how I understand it. There may be more or different things.

Voting on meta questions is very different from all the other sites ("i like/dislike this", versus this is a good/bad Question/answer'"). Many active users hang out on Meta.se as well with their experience and opinions, so you see a lot of up/down votes here.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution. I appreciate your willingness to help, thanks, but I would have liked to bring the questioner into the debate. He/she/they should be the one to answer it and and clarify our doubts.

I’m having a hard time following what you are trying to say. A lot of things seem like non sequiturs, prominently how your observation of many downvotes (a human action thingy) leads to calling for a decentralised solution (a system architecture thingy). Not to mention that I would call some of the claims blatantly false, such as the internet being the cloud. Perhaps you could [edit] this question to try and get your point across more clearly?

@AugustoVasques I like so too. I welcome the questioner to edit or comment on the question in any way. But we are also a collaborative site, we all should work together to make the best Q&A. And I thought that some comments can be discussed immediately. Details in the question remain unclear but the general notion, the question in the title for example, does not. Currently SE is rather centralized. But for all what is worth, please Torsten Dieter Kühnel, edit your question in any way to provide more clarity, respond to comments, etc. Maybe he is a bit intimidated by the intensity of votes, ...

@JanDoggen "Voting on meta questions is very different from all the other sites..." It is, but it's not supposed to be like this. Like/dislike voting shall only apply to feature requests officially. Everything else should be good/bad. Maybe it's because the two are inherently difficult to differentiate for Meta topics which are often opinionated (discussions) anyway.

@JeanotZubler I obviously can't read OP's mind, but their decentralization talk could be about the fediverse where servers communicate with each other (usually via activitypub)

What is “Meta Stack Exchange network” even supposed to mean? There is the Stack Exchange network, and one of the sites there is this Meta.

TL;DR summary: “I randomly landed on this site. I haven’t got the foggiest what it is, what it does, and how it works, but according to my ideological convictions, it’s all wrong. So let me offer some important advice how you guys should run it better.”

@rene "I personally don't think changing the structure will help getting a better reception of new proposals." We can't really change the structure ourselves, so it's already failing at this point. However, I thought about it, if for some reason, the whole effort would have started differently like if the initial idea was let's build a decentralized Q&A based knowledge library, the state today might be different and the disconnect between company and the community might be different. Centralized services maybe really produce different companies.

@EmilJeřábek "TL;DR summary" This is definitely a bad intent assuming summary. Maybe the asker has heard about the advantages of decentralized software systems and is a fan of this site but wonders if both combined might be even better. Lots of people out there are not capable of expressing themselves so clearly as is beneficial here. Our task would be to help them and optimize the content.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Please help them by letting them comment and/or [edit] to clarify what they meant. Wildly speculating and going on tangents is only further derailing whatever they were trying to say.

@MisterMiyagi Sure no problem. I really wish the OP would. But I also think that some commenting must be allowed, especially if I see summaries that read so different from what I perceive. I tried to shield the question but the train wreck happened nevertheless.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I'm not assuming, but inferring from the post, and it's not bad intent, but total cluelessness about the "Meta Stack Exchange network", whatever exactly the OP might mean by it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution. "I really wish the OP would. But I also think that some commenting must be allowed" So don't answer for them, let the users express their thoughts. I'm quite frustrated, maybe I even sound rude, but I'd like to know the user's thoughts on how the application architecture, decentralized or monolithic, impacts on SE UX because I don't see how it affects the user's life. Maybe the user  brings useful ideias or not, but it looks like we won't be hearing about the question's author opinions because someone liked the question so much that decided to take it for oneself.

@AugustoVasques "..it looks like we won't be hearing about the question's author opinions because someone liked the question so much that decided to take it for oneself." Do you really think that is the reason why the original poster did not reply? I understand what you want but I don't understand how commenting on your comment prohibited the original author from answering to you. We both urged him. I should have added some of the comments to the answer instead, but the impact of the votes or other comments should be much higher. I'm also frustrated. I'm frustrated about the community at large

Nope, and I don't think any of the stakeholders have any real incentive to.
At worst the company needs the SE public platforms to prop up various initiatives to grow SAAS businesses until/if they become self sustaining.  There's no Stack Overflow for Teams without Stack Overflow.
While there's offshoots, and independently running communities that spawned off from SE - I think that for all its flaws, the current 'centralised' system's flaws are mostly social rather than structural.
Personally I've got a few criteria for decentralization - is there in value in running your own instance, does it give redundancy from poor management or hardware failure, and such.
An added wrinkle is SE's social software, not a social network and linked personal or organisational instances, to me don't make sense. This works only when we're in the same place.
Solutions for 'ideas' like AI in everything - and at a lower level, a desire to pivot from social software to SAAS are going to be in a different direction could be about conscious decoupling between the community and company or about the company rediscovering value in good community communications and feedback. Rearchitecting the network does neither.

I don't think the idea is so bad actually, but I'm also not aware of any plans of the company here to go in that direction and I'm not aware of extensive user community discussions on Meta here in that direction either. I guess that the benefits for the company, in particular towards their expected profit margin, may be very small or even negative and for the community of users this is a bit too big of a topic to casually discuss it.
However, in general it's probably interesting to discuss how knowledge libraries like this one could be organized, curated and maintained most efficiently. We have huge problems with archiving the knowledge, where the company simply neglects a proper open availability of data dumps. And with lots of new data-driven applications, it's very important for a library to keep access to the stored data as open as possible.
On the other hand, other knowledge collections like Wikipedia are centralized, so there are advantages (not the least less complex development) to a centralized approach within a certain area too. I think that especially consistent curation would be even more challenging than it is already within a decentralized approach.
It's difficult to predict if the advantages of a decentralized approach (autonomy, resilience, ...) outweigh the disadvantages (complexity, organizational problems, ...) and anyway you would have to look at the incentives. The company for example might simply not be interested.
Finally, maybe development of decentralized software/knowledge systems is simply not yet progressed that much to really use them routinely and reliably with manageable effort. You simply might ask this a few (6-8) years of development too early.
